# Laravel Auth::check() precheck

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

on my web page there are 3 options available, Login, Register and Logout.

If I want to display only the available buttons e.g. if the user is loged in I only want to show the logout button, but if the user is a guest they need the login and register buttons.

Now I added a provider to check if the user ist authenticated. Here is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use View;
use Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ShareServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
    */
    public function boot()
    {
        echo "Provider boot check ";
        var_dump(Auth::check());        

        if(Auth::check()) 
        {
            View::share(['loged_in' => true]);
        }
        else 
        {
             View::share(['loged_in' => false]);        
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But the user is every time shown as a guest. When I make the Auth::check() in other controllers, everything works fine. But I dont want to check it in every controller.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you an alternative to achieve a solution to your problem, that works within your contraints.

Rather than having it as a service provider, you could have it as a helper function that you can call in your blades or controllers.

Create a `helpers.php` file and place it as such `app/Http/helpers.php`.

Afterwards add it in your `composer.json` inside the `autoload` array

```
 "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Http/helpers.php"
        ],
```

`composer dump-autoload`, in your terminal afterwards.

Now, inside your `helpers.php` file add the following method:

```
function userLoggedIn(){
    $logged_in = false;
    if(Auth::check()){
        $logged_in = true;
    }
    return $logged_in;
}
```

Now, you should be able to use this method inside any controller/blade.

```
@if(userLoggedIn())
    <p>Logged in</p>
@else
    <p>Not Logged in</p>
@endif
```

This way, you are not having to bear the overhead of having to perform an Auth:check in every controller and you can still use it Anywhere you need it in your project.

Resources: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1